# How to find what service running on background on Android?

Tags: android

How to find what service running on background on Android?
like input method service, ....
Using adb or terminal on android device ?
Could I use "top" or "ps" command?

Maybe I have to ask in another way?
Does the service be presented as one "process", then we can use "ps" or "top" command to find it?

Comment: just found :  adb shell service list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more precise way to show running services is by using `dumpsys`.

To get a list of all running services:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity services
```

To show the status of a particular service:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity services <partial-service-name>
```

For example, if your service name is `com.example.MyService`:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity services MyService
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the emulator or have a connected device, you can launch adb with 'adb shell' from the command line and you can run all those linux binaries like top and ps.